# How to insert a value in Hindi in Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen many tutorials on Firebase but none of the videos showed how to insert a value in any native language. Please help me if anyone has an answer to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what kind of data do you need to place at the database ?

Comment: I want to store words in different languages. Is there any option present of such type in Firebase?

Comment: you can store any language I think, just try with setValue(yourString) and see what happends